# Using a field in initialization list in constructor body

Tags: c++, constructor

In the code below, I have a constructor that initializes `requests` vector in the initialization list using `split_string` function, which is a working function.
I am using the vector in the constructor body, but it throws a segmentation fault if I try to construct a request class with `command line`s.

Why is this giving me an error? What is wrong?

```
class request {
    vector<char*> requests;

    public:

    explicit request(char line[]): requests(split_string(line)) {
        cout << "THIS LINE DOES NOT PRINT" << requests[1] << endl;
    }
```

---

This is the `split_string` code:

```
vector<char*> split_string(char line[]) {
    vector<char*> vec_str;
    char* token;
    token = strtok(line, " ");

    while (token != NULL) {
        vec_str.push_back(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < vec_str.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << vec_str.at(i) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: How was `split_string()` implemented?

Comment: A return statement (`return vec_str;`) does *wonders* for that function. Try adding one.

Comment: A typical input of Line[] is "GET Google.html HTTP/1.0"

Comment: At the very least, your compiler should have given you a warning about the missing `return` statement. If it didn't, you didn't configure it properly.

Comment: @syam I concur. "Not all control paths return values..." should at the very least be a warning, but hey, warnings are more an inconvenience than anything else, right? =P No? =P

Comment: @WhozCraig Warnings are like dialog boxes: when you see one, you should promptly ignore it. In fact, those picky compilers should turn all errors into warnings so that the annoyance level goes down. ;) And to think that some masochists actually use `-Werror`... :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `return` statement in `split_string()`. Thus, `request::requests` wasn't initialized by the correct `vector<char*>`.

Comment: Oh. this was a stupid mistake. I'm sorry for stupid question.